# Return a value from state only when callback is triggered in React

Tags: reactjs

I am using the [react-resizable](https://github.com/STRML/react-resizable) library to resize columns in a table.

Using the library's API, I can call `onSortStart` and `onSortStop` when resizing of the element has started and finished.

When I log in side the triggered callbacks I only see a log once when resizing has started and once when resizing has stopped - so far so good.

But what I want is to be able to return a boolean flag, true when resizing has started and false when resizing has stopped.

The problem is is that the state is changing every time my `useStateful` custom hook is re-created / rendering. So I get hundreds of updated versions of the variable `isResizing`.

How can I just make `isResizing` return true once when started and false once when stopped?

Here is my code:

```js
const ResizableColumn = (props: ResizableColumnProps): ReactElement => {
    const { onResizeStart, onResizeStop } = useStateful();

    const {
        onResize, width, className, children, style,
    } = props;

    if (!width) {
        return <th className={className} style={style}>{children}</th>;
    }
    return (
        <Resizable
            width={width}
            height={0}
            onResize={onResize}
            minConstraints={[150, 150]}
            draggableOpts={{ enableUserSelectHack: false }}
            onResizeStart={onResizeStart}
            onResizeStop={onResizeStop}
        >
            <th className={className} style={style}>{children}</th>
        </Resizable>
    );
};
export default ResizableColumn;
```

useStateful:

```js
const useStateful = (): any => {
  const [isResizing, setIsResizing] = useState(false);
  const onResizeStart = (): void => {
    console.log('%c Resizing Started!', 'color: green;'); // logs once - perfect
    setIsResizing(true);
  };
  const onResizeStop = (): void => {
    console.log('%c Resizing Stopped!', 'color: green;'); // logs once - perfect
    setIsResizing(false);
  };
  console.log('%c isResizing', 'color: green;', isResizing); // logs hundreds of times with different values

  return { isResizing, onResizeStart, onResizeStop };
};
export default useStateful;
```

I have also tried using `useRef` but the same thing happens:

```js
const useStateful = (): any => {

  const isResizing = useRef<boolean>();

  const onResizeStart = (): void => {
    console.log('%c Resizing Started!', 'color: green;'); // logs once - perfect
    isResizing.current = true;
  };
  const onResizeStop = (): void => {
    console.log('%c Resizing Stopped!', 'color: green;'); // logs once - perfect
    isResizing.current = false;
  };
  console.log('%c isResizing', 'color: green;', isResizing.current); // logs hundreds of times with different values

  return { isResizing, onResizeStart, onResizeStop };
};
export default useStateful;
```

Comment: Ciao, I think could be possible but without nothing to work with I could answer with something that is uncomplete... Could you share your github repo? Or make a codesandbox example?

Comment: Hey @GiovanniEsposito thank you it's a huge private repo unfortunately so I can't share much more :(

Comment: No problem. I will try to resolve from your code example :)

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I saw your code for a lot of time and the only thing I noted is that on your custom hook `useStateful` you are returning a different number of elements compared to the line in which you are using your custom hook. I made a small example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-8hrsh?file=/src/index.js).

The custom hook is conceptually equal to yours:

```
const useStateful = () => {
   const [isResizing, setIsResizing] = useState(false);

   const onResizeStart = () => {
     setIsResizing(true);
     console.log("onResizeStart");
   };

   const onResizeStop = () => {
     setIsResizing(false);
     console.log("onResizeStop");
   };

   console.log(isResizing);
   return [isResizing, onResizeStart, onResizeStop];
};
```

But, when I use this hook I wrote:

```
const [isResizing, onResizeStart, onResizeStop] = useStateful();
```

Thats it. I konw that my example could not be what you are looking for but it's a little bit tricky to recreate your environment.